# Stromanthe triostar help

Tags: houseplants, plant-care

as you can see in the photo two of my Stromanthe leaves from the same roots are curling inward. what could be the issue? I don't think it's a humidity or watering issue, nor do I see any visible signs of pests. The roots also looked normal but I noticed that a section of the roots have been severed when I was repotting the plant. Has anyone have any experience with the Stromanthe leaf curling like this? Thanks in advance! 
 [image]